# Can't update to Web API 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to update my Web API from 2.0 to 2.1 but I have the following error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

at this line

`GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`

in the `global.asax.cs` when I run the API after the update.

but it's normal because it's referencing 5.1.0 in the csprog

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

I tried also with the command line

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 5.1.0
```

and I have the same problem but sometimes it gives me an error saying that some plugins depend on `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.core 5.0.0.`

but I don't understand why because the plugin's dependencies are `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.core >= 5.0.0.`
so 5.1.0 should work.

I tried to update and ignore dependencies with

```
Install-Package -Ignoredependencies Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 5.1.0
```

and I don't have the error anymore but the API returns error 500.

Any idea why the update to Web API 2.1 doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have assembly binding redirect?

```
<runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
           <dependentAssembly>
               <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
               <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
           </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: It works now! Is the Package Manager Console supposed to add this? Thank you

Comment: Yes, installation powershell script is supposed to add or update this. Maybe an error occured somewhere internally? Try to reproduce it in an empty project, and if yes, a bug report is welcomed on project's github.